# PHP Redirect condition

Tags: php, redirect

I am working on a script to detect if the user is close enough to our location to display the local version of our website located on a subdomain. I'm looking for help where I should insert this and the best method of redirection from WordPress

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
$clean = substr($details->loc, 0, -1);
$coord = explode(',', $clean);
$latitudeFrom = floatval($coord[0]);
$longitudeFrom = floatval($coord[1]);
echo "Long: ".$longitudeFrom."\r\n";
echo "Lat: ".$latitudeFrom."\r\n";

$longitudeTo = -68.6833;
$latitudeTo = 33.1711;
$radius = 50; //miles

  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  echo $latDelta."\r\n";
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
  echo $lonDelta."\r\n";

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  $distance = $angle * 3959;

  if ($distance < $radius) {
    //redirect to local page
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run as early as possible, which makes sense if you want to avoid loading unnecessary assets, put the code in a function in a [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), and hook that function to the [`muplugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded) action.

```
<?php

add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'wpd_my_redirector' );

function wpd_my_redirector() {

    // your code here
    // wp_redirect is not defined this early, so we use php's header

    if( $somecondition === true ){
        header( 'Location: ' . home_url( '/your-local-page/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the functions.php file of your theme, I would add an action that hooks to template_redirect, like this (untested) below:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse251614_redirect_to_local_site'    );

    function wpse251614_redirect_to_local_site(){
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
        $clean = substr($details->loc, 0, -1);
        $coord = explode(',', $clean);
        $latitudeFrom = floatval($coord[0]);
        $longitudeFrom = floatval($coord[1]);
        echo "Long: ".$longitudeFrom."\r\n";
        echo "Lat: ".$latitudeFrom."\r\n";

        $longitudeTo = -68.6833;
        $latitudeTo = 33.1711;
        $radius = 50; //miles

        $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
        $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
        $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
        $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

        $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
        echo $latDelta."\r\n";
        $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
        echo $lonDelta."\r\n";

        $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
        cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
        $distance = $angle * 3959;

        if ($distance < $radius) {
            //redirect to local page
            wp_redirect(LOCAL_PAGE);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/